# English: I needed to check in at a hotel I booked online

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'd like to know the sentences for checking in at a hotel I booked online. I know normally I can say

> "I'd like to check in under the name of ..."

But if I want to specifically express that I booked this hotel on agoda(a website where you can book hotels), what should I say?

For example, how about

> "Hi, I am checking in. I booked a room for tonight and tomorrow night using agoda/ on agoda"

Also, I want to confirm that the whole package includes breakfast and dinner, what should I ask to the front desk when checking in?

For example, how about

> "Also I'd like to confirm that the room I booked comes with dinner and breakfast"

Comment: This is not really English language advice so much as it is hotel advice, but hotels will your reservation recorded under your name, regardless of what booking service you used.  So the fastest way to check in would be to say, "Hi, I have a reservation under the name [your last name]."  If you want to specify your booking service, you can add, "I booked it with Agoda."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These examples are all quite reasonable and understandable. Hotels will your reservation recorded under your name, regardless of what booking service you used. So the fastest way to check in would be to say, "Hi, I have a reservation under the name [your last name]." If you want to specify your booking service, you can add, "I booked it with Agoda."

Indeed in this situation, almost anything would be understood. "[Last name]" would be  enough, since the social context of going to a hotel implies "I want to check in" and saying your name implies "And I have a reservation under this name."